# Adding Pointcut on a random line inside a function

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop

Can i add Pointcut on a random line inside a function?? For example If control goes inside a particular if block the code in @Before should be executed. If yes, please mention how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What stops you from putting these lines in a new method and add the pointcut there?

Comment: Yes I can definitely do that. Just wanted to know if the above mentioned scenario is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As of today spring supports aspects at method level only. As Sofo Gial suggested you should refactor ur code ,move the logic in a method and then u can apply point cut on that method. This will also help in unit testing ur aspect.

Hope that helps.